# Retrieving (allpost) data from firebase and using uid want to retrieve user information also

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want retrieve all post then with each post there is a uid, using this uid i want to retrieve user information

My code is like this but it is not working and state is not changing in then block

```js
getAllPost(){ 
    let allPost = firebase.database().ref("all-post");
    let postAll = [];
    allPost.once("value").then(data => {
      data.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        let childData = childSnapshot.val();
        childData.postId = childSnapshot.key;
        let userInfo = firebase.database().ref(`users/${childData.uid}`);
        userInfo.once("value").then(data => {
          childData.userInfo = data;
          postAll.push(childData);        
        })
      })
    }).then(()=>{
      this.setState({ allPost: postAll,loading: false  },);
    }).catch(err => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    });
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that you are running async calls in forEach, which is synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Josh commented, you're not handling the fact that all your `userInfo.once()` calls are asynchronous. This means that right now your `this.setState({ allPost: postAll,loading: false  },)` call fires before the `postAll.push(childData)` happen. You should be able to easily see this by adding some `console.log` statements.

The solution is to wait until all the loading is finished, by using `Promise.all()`:

```
let allPost = firebase.database().ref("all-post");
let postAll = [];
allPost.once("value").then(data => {
  let promises = [];
  data.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    let childData = childSnapshot.val();
    childData.postId = childSnapshot.key;
    let userInfo = firebase.database().ref(`users/${childData.uid}`);
    promises.push(
      userInfo.once("value").then(data => {
        childData.userInfo = data;
        postAll.push(childData);        
      })
    })
  })
  return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(()=>{
  this.setState({ allPost: postAll,loading: false },);
}).catch(err => {
  this.setState({ loading: false });
});
```

Comment: Frank van Puffelen, Thankyou very much this is working fine for me, You saved my life.